# Importing time sliced samples into Electribe Sampler

Tags: daw, drum-machine, looping

The editing of time slices of samples on the Korg Electribe is a real pain.

Is there a way to export my own time sliced samples from my DAW to the Electribe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The executive summary of this is:

- Time slice your sample in your DAW (in Reaper it's Dynamic Split) so that there are 8 or 16 slices for your sample.
- Save each slice. Choose a name and a cardinal number to keep track of where each slice is in the overall sample. For example: `Sample-01.wav, Sample-02.wav,...`
- Import each sample into the Electribe.
- Create a new pattern in the Electribe
- Assign the slices to pads in the pattern.
- Write the pattern